# PHP - download dialog box for given videos url

Tags: php, video

I am pretty new in php .so hopefully this all make sense . I am using below script to extract url from database.I want down-loader will popup in browser while reading the url from database....

```
 $q="  Select url from videos where id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'   ";
     $result=mysql_query($q);
           while( $rows =mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
            {
        $url=$rows['url '];
    //here i want code to send this url to down-loader of browser..
    //and browser should popup the down-loader
        $myarray1=array("url "=>$url );
             }
```

I have searched codes on google but i don't understand how to use for this scenario...

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection, you know.

Comment: No go, take a look at MySQLi / PDO. Old MySQL way is deprecated. + what @BenM said.

Comment: You can open popup using jquery. Store URL in a variable and use jquery to open.

Comment: please tell the code for completing this task in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to fix the SQL Injection problem.
Use MySQLi instead of MySQL

Here's a code:

```
$request_id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
if(!empty($request_id)){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database_name");
    $request_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($request_id);
    $query = "SELECT url FROM videos WHERE id='" . $request_id . "'";
    $query_result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if(!empty($query_result)){
        if($query_result->num_rows > 0){
            $my_result_array = array();
            while($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()){
                $my_result_array[] = $row['url'];
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

Concerning the download problem, you need to redirect the user to a PHP page with a specific header

```
<?php
$file_name = "";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
?>
```

You need to add the `$file_name` and the specific `Content-Type`.
Here's a list of Content-Types: http://davidwalsh.name/php-header-mime

In order to redirect a user to the download page, you can use the PHP `header()` function.